# Como fazer SELECT com ORDER BY e critérios diferentes?

Tags: mysql

Galera tem como fazer um select com 2 "ORDER BY"?

Tabela *CATEGORIA*:

[image: Dados da Tabela]

Se eu fizer um SELECT assim:

```
select id,nome from CATEGORIA ORDER BY nome ASC
```

O MySQL me retorna os nomes em ordem alfabética, porém preciso que ele me retorne sempre o *id:100* em primeiro e apresente os outros em ordem alfabética pela coluna *Nome*.

Tem como fazer isso em um único SELECT?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

O `ORDER BY` permite que você especifique vários critérios:

```
SELECT ... ORDER BY expressao1, expressao2, expressao3...
```

No seu caso, basta isso:

```
SELECT id, nome FROM categoria ORDER BY id != 100, nome
```

Veja funcionando perfeitamente no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52a4c3/1)**.

- A expressão `id != 100` vai retornar `false`, que é ordenado antes de `true`, deixando o registro escolhido sempre em primeiro. Como critério de desempate, será usado `nome`.
- Você pode usar várias condições em seguida no mesmo `ORDER` quando precisar de mais de um critério, basta ordenar do mais importante para o menos importante, separando por vírgula.

  Exemplo: `ORDER BY idade, nome, pontos` ordenará por `idade`, mas quando a idade "empatar", vai ordenar por `nome`, e apenas no caso de `idade` e `nome` serem iguais é que a ordenação se dará por `pontos`.
- A palavra chave `ASC` é desnecessária, pois a ordenação ascendente é o padrão do banco, mas nada impede de você manter. De curiosidade, poderia usar `ORDER BY id = 100 DESC, nome ASC` que daria no mesmo.

Comment: Achei o seu código bem melhor e mais explicativo do que os outros,não é necessário complicar para algo de modo tão fácil de se fazer.

Comment: @Falion grato, a idéia era simplificar mesmo. Tem outras respostas que resolveram bem também, mas apesar de termos várias respostas já, preferi mostrar esse caminho mais curto.

Comment: @Bacco achei que a minha seria mais simples antes de ver está,rsrs. +1 bela simplificada.

Comment: @Marconi as nossas são bem parecidas, eu só dei uma "limada maior nas arestas" por assim dizer. A linha geral é a mesma.

Comment: @Bacco com certeza essa foi uma resposta sensacional. :)

Comment: Muito bom, eu não sabia que podia executar expressões no `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @Bacco acha que valeria a pena edita o titulo dessa pergunta para: Como adicionar critérios no order by? Creio que a pergunta ficaria mais ampla, assim abrangendo a um público maior.

Comment: @Marconi tentei chegar num consenso entre sua sugestão e o título original. Não ficou tão curtinho, mas acho que aumenta a chance de encontrar em uma pesquisa.

Comment: Bacana @Bacco, de vez em quando eu faço isso com o intuito de buscar mais leitores. obrigado!

Answer (score 15):

Use *Case When*. No meu exemplo só o registro com id *100* será 1, então será retornado primeiro.

Os outros registros sempre retornaram 2 o que irá ocorrer um empate, o que passa a valer o segundo critério no `Order by`.

## Criação da Tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testes](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [nome] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

insert into testes(id,nome)
values(100,'ESTOQUE');

insert into testes(id,nome)
values(101,'VENDAS');

insert into testes(id,nome)
values(102,'CONTAS');
```

## Query:

```
select *
from testes
order by CASE WHEN id = 100 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, nome
```

## [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9780c5/2)

Answer (score 8):

Consegui que o `100` viesse sempre em primeiro usando duas consultas:

```
select id, nome from CATEGORIA where id = 100
union 
(select id, nome from CATEGORIA where id != 100 ORDER BY nome ASC)
;
```

Note que a segunda consulta precisa estar entre parênteses, caso contrário o `ORDER BY` ordenará as duas consultas.

Comment: Alterei a consulta para trazer somente o 100 primeiro, independente da ordenação.

Answer (score 6):

Acredito que assim funcione, testei em outro banco e deu certo, não sei se vai funcionar no MySql.

```
select tabela.id, tabela.nome
from (select 1 as ordem, id, nome from categoria where id= 100
      union
      select 2 as ordem, id, nome from categoria where id != 100
      order by 1,3) as tabela
```

Comment: Não entendi porque do voto negativo. Pode não ser a melhor forma ou a resposta mais aceitável. Concordo com @EmersonJS quando ele diz que tem várias formar de se fazer e está é uma da N formas de se fazer. Tive o cuidado de testar no Firebird (banco de utilizo com frequência), porém, fiz a ressalva de não saber se funcionava no MySQL, até por questões de sintaxe.

Comment: Exatamente. Até onde sabemos, a intenção é votar positivo nas melhores respostas, e não votar negativo em uma **resposta correta**. Votos negativos devem ser utilizados para respostas incorretas ou intencionalmente negligentes. Mas infelizmente vemos muitos votos negativos sem nenhuma justificativa. Talvez o pessoal precise ler as instruções novamente. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Answer (score 6):

Você já tem várias respostas, este é apenas mais um jeito de se fazer:

```
SELECT id, 
       nome, 
       CASE 
          WHEN id = 100 THEN " "
          ELSE nome
       END AS ordenacao
  FROM categoria
 ORDER BY ordenacao
```

Criamos uma **coluna calculada** para ordenar a `SELECT`.

Quando o `ID` for igual a **100** a coluna calculada vale um **espaço em branco**, quando `ID` for outro valor qualquer, a coluna será igual a coluna `NOME`.

Desta forma, quando ordenarmos, a linha com o **espaço em branco virá primeiro**.

Answer (score 4):

Adicione uma coluna nova na tabela chamada "position". Enfim, o nome pode ser qualquer outro que desejar.

Para o ID 100, salve a coluna "position" como 1, as outras deixe como 0 ou nulo.

Então no momento de consultar, basta ordenar pela coluna "position" em ordem descrescente com prioridade sobre as outras regras de ordenação.

```
select id,nome from CATEGORIA ORDER BY position DESC, nome ASC;
```

Esteja ciente de que não quer dizer que é a melhor e tampouco a única solução.

Particularmente prefiro dessa forma comparando com outras sugestões apresentadas pois torna mais flexível. Pense quando precisar atribuir a prioridade para um ID diferente ou quando quiser reaproveitar a rotina para outras coisas. Terá que mudar no código manualmente e fazer gambiarras e adaptações diversas.

Comment: hum, dessa forma eu teria que criar mais uma coluna na tabela, essa é a única forma?

Comment: É apenas mais um jeito de resolver. Para qualquer outra solução sem adicionar uma coluna nova, terá que fazer subqueries ou dupla consulta, ou condicionais estranhas que dificultam numa migração para outro SGDB, ou ainda, implementar uma query um pouco mais complicada para fazer algo tão simples. Por isso, apenas postei isso como sugestão. Não quer dizer que é a melhor e tampouco a única solução. O que parece ser simples pelo tamanho do código pode na verdade ser pior.

Answer (score -1):

coloque o sinal nas variáveis de ordenação

```
select id,nome from CATEGORIA ORDER BY 'position' DESC, 'nome' ASC;
```