# Com fazer a SQL ordenar e randomizar ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: sql

**Tenho o seguinte código:**

```
(SELECT id, slug 
 FROM anuncios 
 WHERE vum = '$idcategoria'
 ORDER BY RAND()) 
ORDER BY publicado DESC
```

Preciso que o SQL ordene e ao mesmo tempo randomize, só que de o código acima apenas está fazendo a ordenação, a randomização não funciona.

Segue imagem real de exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A imagem acima é o que estou tentando fazer funcionar, observe que temos duas primeiras publicidades possuem o campo (publicidade=2) com banner,  e as três últimas sem banner possuem o campo (publicidade=1). Preciso que as duas primeiras que possuem o campo (publicidade=2) sejam as primeiras a serem exibidas (mas que a cada atualização da página estas duas publicidades randomizem). Já as publicidades que possuem o campo (publicidade=1) restantes também randomizem.

Comment: Como assim? Ou você ordena ou não os dados. O máximo que vc vai conseguir é randomizar uma amostra, colocando um top 10 por exemplo, assim vc teria 10 registros escolhidos aleatoriamente mas ordenados pela data de publicação.

Comment: @jean Preciso que o SQL exiba dados ordenados pois tenho um campo que possui dois valores (publicado=1 e publicado=2) que ordene na ordem ASC o campo publicado, mas que randomize também.

Comment: Gladison, coloca um exemplo mínimo de como estão seus registros e como você espera que seja o retorno do select.

Comment: A cláusula `ORDER BY` vai apenas ordenar pelos campos que vc mandar, em relação aos outros campos não há ordenação oq significa que vai pegar uma "ordem arbitrária" (random) em relação aos outros campos mas que, em geral, vai sempre pegar a mesma ordem arbitrária.

Comment: @jean Neste caso como faço para que o rand também funcione?

Comment: Vc ñ entendeu ainda, o `RAND` está funcionando e entregando um dataset aleatoriamente ordenado para a ordenação por data de publicação mas como essa ordenação ignora todos os outros campos os outros campos vão vir "desordenados" mas vão vir geralmente desordenados da mesma maneira

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como fazer SELECT com ORDER BY e critérios diferentes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136136/como-fazer-select-com-order-by-e-crit%c3%a9rios-diferentes)

Comment: Basta um ORDER BY publicado DESC, RAND() (vide pergunta do link sugerido de fechamento)

Answer (score -1):

Boa tarde,
Ao utilizar o RAND() o número será igual para todas as linhas.

Pelo que entendo o objectivo é garantir que os anúncios "publicados" com o valor 2 surjam sempre em primeiro lugar.
Assumindo que o grau de importância dos anúncios se mantém desta forma (3 aparecerá primeiro que 2, caso exista), a forma correcta de o fazer é:

```
 SELECT NewID() rnd, id, slug FROM anuncios
ORDER BY publicado DESC, rnd
```

Comment: Enquanto isso pode funcionar p/ MySql ou TSQL não vai funcionar para Oracle e OP não "tagueou" o SGBD

Answer (score -2):

Olá o que você terá que fazer é separar isso em 2 queries, gerar um elemento único e randômico e então utilizar esse elemento para fazer o order by mas, sem selecioná-lo. Assim:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Foo (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    nome NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Foo (nome) VALUES 
    ('João'), ('Maria'), ('José'), ('Antônio'), ('André'), 
    ('Lucas'), ('Leandro'), ('Samuel'), ('Lorena'), ('Filipe');

SELECT
    id, nome
FROM
    (SELECT id, nome, NEWID() as random FROM Foo) as x
ORDER BY
    random
```

Se você usar dessa forma, cada linha terá um novo elemento de referencia e, então a ordenação resolverá, sem a necessidade de criação de campo adicional...

Espero que ajude.