# order by por texto especifico

Tags: sql, sql-server

Como faço um `order by` por critério de texto?

Tenho uma coluna com algumas classificações e queria que viesse na ordem que eu determinar.

Exemplo:

```
'carro1'
'carro3'
'carro5'
'carro10'
'carro2'
```

Comment: Maikol, a ideia ainda não ficou mto clara.. poderia expor mais detalhes?

Comment: e o que seria a order que você determinar ?

Comment: Opa. Eu tenho uma coluna com algumas classificações e queria exibir o resultado da consulta com as classificações na ordem que eu determinar.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como fazer SELECT com ORDER BY e critérios diferentes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136136/como-fazer-select-com-order-by-e-crit%c3%a9rios-diferentes)

Comment: Para o seu caso específico, é só pegar substring e fazer cast to int, que o carro 10 virá no final. Mas o problema real não é esse, provavelmente. Isso é conhecido como Problema XY, que é quando você pergunta sobre a solução que acha que vai resolver, em vez de expor o problema real.

Comment: acho que o problema mesmo é na forma de armazenar o dado... "exibir o resultado na ordem que eu determinar" se for pra determinar a ordem de cada item, melhor criar uma coluna e  ordenar por ela

Comment: Rovann, fiz isso mesmo e foi a solução. obrigado, abs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você poderia criar uma coluna de classificação.

Pelo que entendi são poucos registros, então criando uma coluna de classificação, você poderia dar uma numeração para cada um dos registro da sua listagem, dessa forma caso no futuro surja alguma no categoria, basta editar no banco, ou até mesmo fazer um menu administrativo para tal fim.

---

Mas se mesmo assim quiser filtra especificamente pelos registros citados, segue um exemplo de uma "Solução Emergencial Paliativa temporária", vulgo "gambiarra".

```
SELECT
  carName
FROM
  exemple

ORDER BY
CASE carName
    WHEN 'carro1' THEN 0
    WHEN 'carro3' THEN 1
    WHEN 'carro5' THEN 2
    WHEN 'carro10' THEN 3
    WHEN 'carro2' THEN 4
    ELSE 999
END
```

Exemplo testável:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/49da0/11

Comment: David, obrigado, deu certo. Abs.