# Ordenar no SQL priorizando um valor de um campo específico

Tags: php, sql, select

Tenho uma grande tabela de clientes, e preciso selecionar os seguintes campos (dados exemplo)

```
id | id_ls | id_sistema_ls | nome | ativo
----------------------------------------
 1 | 1007  |    158849     |   A  |   0
 2 | 1187  |     849       |   B  |   1
 3 | 19726 |    26606      |   C  |   1 
 4 | 5718  |    98756      |   D  |   0
 5 | 6466  |     122       |   E  |   1
 6 | 11825 |      18       |   F  |   1
```

Eu possuo um array de `id_ls` que posso selecionar, então minha query original seria

```
SELECT id, id_ls, id_sistema_ls, nome, ativo FROM clientes WHERE id_ls IN (1007,1187,3050,5718,6466,11825,12067,12490) GROUP BY id_ls ORDER BY ativo DESC, nome ASC
```

Essa query me retorna o resultado exemplificado lá em cima dessa forma

```
id | id_ls | id_sistema_ls | nome | ativo
----------------------------------------
 2 | 1187  |     849       |   B  |   1
 3 | 19726 |    26606      |   C  |   1 
 5 | 6466  |     122       |   E  |   1
 6 | 11825 |      18       |   F  |   1
 1 | 1007  |    158849     |   A  |   0
 4 | 5718  |    98756      |   D  |   0
```

Está funcionando corretamente. Entretanto, agora preciso priorizar uma sequencia específica de `id_sistema_ls`, trazendo-os primeiro e só então seguindo a ordenação. Por exemplo, quero que primeiro seja o `id_sistema_ls` **26606** depois o **18**, e então siga-se o resultado inicial. Ficando desta forma:

```
id | id_ls | id_sistema_ls | nome | ativo
----------------------------------------
 3 | 19726 |    26606      |   C  |   1 
 6 | 11825 |      18       |   F  |   1

 2 | 1187  |     849       |   B  |   1
 5 | 6466  |     122       |   E  |   1
 1 | 1007  |    158849     |   A  |   0
 4 | 5718  |    98756      |   D  |   0
```

Eu tenho um array que pode conter até 9 números ordenados por prioridade. E preciso respeitá-lo. Tentei seguir [esta solução](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104055/ordering-by-specific-field-value-first) que encontrei no *stackoverflow*. Fiz o seguinte:

```
SELECT id, id_ls, id_sistema_ls, nome, ativo FROM clientes WHERE id_ls IN (1007,1187,3050,5718,6466,11825,12067,12490) GROUP BY id_ls ORDER BY FIELD (id_sistema_ls, 26606, 18), ativo DESC, nome ASC
```

Mas não funcionou. Segue trazendo o mesmo resultado da query sem o FIELD. Alguém sabe me dizer a razão? Ou se existe alguma maneira de eu fazer sem deixar a query super lenta?

O projeto manipula milhares de resultados e performance é importante. Também é importante manter todos os resultados numa query só devido paginação já implementada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse tipo de controle parece estranho de colocar no SQL, talvez seja mais interessante fazer essa ordenação usando uma linguagem mais completa.

Se usar SQL for realmente a única alternativa, você pode usar um `CASE`:

```sql
SELECT id, id_ls, id_sistema_ls, nome, ativo FROM clientes
  WHERE id_ls IN (1007,1187,3050,5718,6466,11825,12067,12490)
  GROUP BY id_ls
  ORDER BY
    CASE id_sistema_ls
      WHEN 26606 THEN 0
      WHEN 18 THEN 1
      ELSE 2
    END,
    ativo DESC,
    nome ASC
```

Fica meio difícil de ler e manter, por isso recomendo tentar alguma alternativa se possível.

Comment: Funcionou @GBrant! Obrigada por contribuir :)

Answer (score 2):

É possível aplicar uma regra CASE ao order by

```
...
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN id_sistema_ls = 26606 THEN 0
               WHEN id_sistema_ls = 18    THEN 1
               ELSE 2 END),id_sistema_ls
```

Comment: Funcionou @Motta! Mesma solução apontada pelo @GBrant. Obrigada por contribuir :)

Answer (score 0):

A minha resposta é igual as outras mas mostro uma outra alternativa de utilizar o `ORDER BY`, veja:

```
SELECT id
      ,id_ls
      ,id_sistema_ls
      ,nome
      ,ativo 
  FROM clientes 
 WHERE id_ls IN (1007,1187,3050,5718,6466,11825,12067,12490) 
 GROUP BY id_ls
 ORDER BY id_sistema_ls not in (26606, 18), ativo DESC, nome ASC
```

Desta maneira você consegue por o *seu array que pode conter até 9 números ordenados por prioridade* sem ter que utilizar o `case`, assim não deixando a manutenção difícil.

Minha base foi [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136136/como-fazer-select-com-order-by-e-crit%C3%A9rios-diferentes).