# Obter um resultado que apareça em 1ª posição, se possuir um valor especificado em SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, query, filter

Preciso criar uma `query` que siga algumas regras e elas são:

1. **gsm** que se repetir
2. **motivo_envio** que seja diferente
3. **status** que esteja com *ANOMALIA* e que apareça como o 1º
       resultado (por cima dos demais)

Irei dar um exemplo de como os dados aparecem, e quais dados preciso obter(*):

```
  gsm   motivo_envio     status     data_ativacao
_________________________________________________
| 111 |     aaa      |  LIBERADO   | 02/01/2019 |
| 111 |     aaa      |  ANOMALIA   | 01/01/2019 |
| 111 |     bbb      |  PENDENTE   | 25/12/2018 |
-------------------------------------------------
| 222 |     aaa      |  ANOMALIA   | 02/01/2019 | *
| 222 |     bbb      |  PENDENTE   | 01/01/2019 |
-------------------------------------------------
| 333 |     aaa      |  ANOMALIA   | 02/02/2019 | *
| 333 |     bbb      |  ANOMALIA   | 01/03/2019 | *
-------------------------------------------------
| 444 |     aaa      |  DEFINITIVA | 02/01/2019 |
| 444 |     bbb      |  ANOMALIA   | 01/01/2019 | *
-------------------------------------------------
| 555 |     bbb      |  LIBERADO   | 02/01/2019 |
| 555 |     aaa      |  ANOMALIA   | 22/04/2019 | *
| 555 |     bbb      |  ANALISE    | 02/01/2019 |
-------------------------------------------------
| 666 |     aaa      |  LIBERADO   | 02/01/2019 |
| 666 |     bbb      |  ANOMALIA   | 02/01/2019 | *
| 666 |     ccc      |  ANOMALIA   | 04/01/2019 | *
| 666 |     ccc      |  PENDENTE   | 07/01/2019 |
| 666 |     ddd      |  ANOMALIA   | 02/01/2019 | *
-------------------------------------------------
```

Irei explicar os resultados:

> Os números 111 não foram pegos pois esses dados só seguem a 1ª e 2ª regra **gsm** que se repete **motivo_envio** que seja diferente, mas o **status** de *ANOMALIA* está por último quem está por cima é o *LIBERADO*.

---

> Os números 222 foi pego somente a que está com *ANOMALIA* pois segue os filtros, **gsm** que se repete **motivo_envio** que seja diferente e **status** com *ANOMALIA* e está por cima.

---

> Os números 333 foram pegos os dois, pois seguem os filtros e ambos só tem um registro em cada **motivo_envio** o que os colocam em 1º lugar ou seja por cima.

---

> Os números 444 foi pego o que está com *ANOMALIA* pois seguem os filtros.

---

> Os números 555 foi pego o que está com *ANOMALIA* pois seguem os filtros.

---

> Os números 666 foram pegos 3 registros sendo que o do **motivo_envio** `bbb` aparece uma única vez e está com *ANOMALIA* e o **motivo_envio** `ccc` aparecem 2 vezes sendo que o 1º lugar é o **status** com *ANOMALIA* e o **motivo_envio** `ddd` aparece também uma única vez e está com *ANOMALIA*.

Tentei criar uma query para obter esses resultados esperados mas a consulta traz resultados indesejados:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT a.gsm, a.motivo_envio, a.status
FROM export b
INNER JOIN ( SELECT * FROM export a WHERE a.status = 'ANOMALIA' ) AS a ON a.gsm = b.gsm
WHERE 
      ( 
        b.status = 'PENDENTE'  
        OR b.status = 'LIBERADO'
        OR b.status = 'ANALISE'
        OR b.status = 'DEFINITIVA'
      ) 
AND b.motivo_envio <> a.motivo_envio
```

Criei um banco de dados [online](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nASFfqYbSFJgpV4yyhzgeb/0) para testar

O **insert** do banco está [aqui](https://pastebin.com/tExiFUEx)

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: O que precisamente você quer dizer com "(por cima dos demais)"? Qual a ordenação que está considerando já que, por definição, o modelo relacional não apresenta uma ordenação implícita.

Comment: ainda está um pouco confuso, consegue montar uma lista só com os resultados de como espera que retorne?

Comment: @RicardoPontual eu coloquei os resultados que preciso obter no exemplo marcado com um * mas aqui está a lista desses resultados que preciso obter: https://pastebin.com/Xxec9ycq

Comment: @anonimo então mano, esse "por cima dos demais" é só uma forma de expressar, para falar que preciso que a ANOMALIA esteja aparecendo primeiro, por exemplo se você arreparar os números 111 eles não foram pegos pois esses dados só seguem a 1ª e 2ª regra,  mas o status de ANOMALIA está por último quem está por cima é o LIBERADO, ou seja só poderia ter pego se a ANOMALIA tivesse por cima. Tentei explicar isso um pouco melhor logo abaixo do exemplo, se puder me ajudar mano, preciso muito disso e não estou conseguindo.

Comment: E estar "por cima dos demais" significa que o status é da data mais recente (ou mais antiga)? Você tem que informar qual é o critério de ordenação para definir o "estar por cima".

Comment: @anonimo como esse foi um exemplo só para demonstração mesmo, a planilha onde tiro esses dados possui muitos campos e 3 deles são para Datas, e o método de ordenação delas é a data mais recente mesmo, ou seja o registro que tiver por cima terá a data mais recente.

Comment: Então pegue o MAX(sua_data) e verifique se é ANOMALIA.

Comment: @anonimo eu sou iniciante com bancos de dados uma vez tentei usar o MAX em data e não deu muito certo, você se puder poderia escrever esse query para eu poder testar? tenho um banco de dados online só no ponto de escrever a query: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/juHY8NoPG3oSEXmSyNCSQK/0   se puder agradeço, to precisando muito fazer isso funcionar.

Comment: 1 e 2 são condições corriqueiras, e o 3 é basicamente isso [Como fazer SELECT com ORDER BY e critérios diferentes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136136/70)

Comment: @Bacco estou tendo problema na criação, não ta dando certo, teria como me dar um exemplo dessa 3ª parte do filtro?

Comment: Sim, tem no [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136136/70)

Comment: Tipo da coisa que eu faria por FUNCTION dada a complexidade da regra.

Comment: @Motta eu não sei criar function ainda :/ sou iniciante com BD, tava precisando muito desenvolver esse filtro, mas não estou conseguindo finaliza-lo

Comment: @Bacco fiz essa query:          select a.* from export a where a.status = 'ANOMALIA' and exists ( select b.gsm from export b where b.gsm = a.gsm )          

E está pegando tudo que preciso, só que está pegando o número 111 com ANOMALIA sendo que não era para pegar, pois o status LIBERADO está por cima do de ANOMALIA, tentei realizar a ordenação conforme me mandou o link mas não funcionou fiz assim: ... order by a.status = 'ANOMALIA'   não me retorna erro, mas não altera em nada o resultado.

Comment: @Magno: é impossível no SQL, particularmente no PostgreSQL, você garantir uma ordem das linhas recuperadas de uma tabela sem utilizar a cláusula ORDER BY. Na tabela que você colocou no fiddle você não tem os campos necessários a tal ordenação.

Comment: @anonimo eu editei a pergunta acrescentei o campo de Data, e mudei o banco de dados online no Fiddle com esses novos dados.

Comment: @anonimo aqui está um print da minha fonte de dados é dai que mando os dados para o banco de dados e executo as querys, é uma planilha que possui varios campos e dois campos que acredito servir para comparação seria o NUM que é um campo que atribui um número sequêncial e a coluna de Datas: https://prnt.sc/odvrth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Magno, Fiz uma adaptações, veja se isso resolve a tua dúvida.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iDMiXohGAFLqxBG2bm2HvX/0

Veja que um dos casos não vai retornar conforme o esperado (o 666), uma vez que a data do tipo PENDENTE é maior que o da ANOMALIA.
A posição de inserção não é o que irá determinar o registro, mas a data que a consulta está ordenando.

```
with cte as (
    select gsm, motivo_envio, status, to_char(data_ativacao, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as data_ativacao,
    rank () OVER (Partition by gsm,motivo_envio order by data_ativacao desc) as ranking
    from export
)
select * from cte
where status = 'ANOMALIA' and ranking = 1
```

Comment: Cara muito obrigado pela atenção lá no grupo do SQL Server no Telegram, e pela disposição em me ajudar, era isso que precisava, literalmente você compreendeu os resultados que eu precisava obter, muito obrigado!